# Infinite sum of recursive integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, summation

Given, $$I_n = \int_0^1 e^{x}x^{n}dx\ $$

Find:  $$\left\lceil \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{I_{k+1}}{I_k} \right\rceil$$

---

I tried to define $I_n$ using a recursive pattern in the following way:

\begin{align}
I_n &= \int_0^1e^{x}x^{n}\text{d}x\\
&=  e - \int_0^1 e^{x}\cdot n\cdot x^{n-1}\text{d}x\  \text{(using integration by parts)}\\
&= e - n\cdot  I_{n-1}
\end{align}
Equivalently,

$ \frac{I_{n+1}}{I_n} = \frac{e}{I_n} - (n+1) $

So, the sum becomes: 
\begin{align}
&\ e(\frac{1}{I_{n}} + \frac{1}{I_{n-1}} + \frac{1}{I_{n-2}} +\cdots + \frac{1}{I_{1}}) - ((n+1) + n + (n-1) + \cdots+2)\\
&=\ e(\frac{1}{I_{n}} + \frac{1}{I_{n-1}} + \frac{1}{I_{n-2}} +\cdots + \frac{1}{I_{1}}) +1 - (\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2})
\end{align}

But now I am stuck and don't know how to proceed, I also found out that $ I_0 = e-1 $ and $ I_1 = 1 $ and few more $I_n$ but that did not lead me anywhere, or at least, I could not get anything from there.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your variables on the limit at the top are all off.

Comment: Sorry, corrected it.

Comment: Note that it is easy to see that $I_k\to 0$, simply use $0\leq \exp(x)\leq e$. Now from your formula, you get $nI_{n-1}\to e$, hence $u_n=\frac{I_{n+1}}{I_n}\to 1$, and your series $u_n$ is divergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D_n$ be the number of [derangements](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derangement.html) in $S_n$, i.e.
$$ D_n=n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.\tag{1} $$
By induction we have
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{1}x^n e^{x}\,dx = (-1)^n \left(eD_n-n!\right)\tag{2} $$
as well as
$$ (n+1) I_n = e - I_{n+1},\qquad \frac{1}{n+1}\leq I_n\leq\frac{e}{n+1}\tag{3} $$
hence $\frac{I_{n+1}}{I_n}\to 1$ and the given series is divergent.